# How to group a list of objects by date in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

```
<#setting date_format="dd/MM/yyyy">
<#assign data1 = "14/05/2016" />
<#assign data2 = "20/05/2016" />
<#assign data3 = "19/06/2016" />
<#assign events_list = [
  {"name":"Event Lorem", "date":data1?date},
  {"name":"Event Lipsum", "date":data2?date},
  {"name":"Event Free", "date":data2?date},
  {"name":"Event Dolor", "date":data3?date},
  {"name":"Event Sit", "date":data1?date}
] />
```

I have this list of events and I sorted them by date:

```
<h5>Order by date:</h5>
<#list events_list?sort_by("date") as event>
    <p>${event.name}: ${event.date}</p>
</#list>
```

[image]

Now I want to **group** them by date because each one can have hours.
Like in this example:

[image]

How can I accomplish this in Freemarker?

Comment: Did you figure out the answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
<#setting date_format="dd/MM/yyyy">
<#assign dataNull = "01/01/1900" />
<#assign data1 = "14/05/2016" />
<#assign data2 = "20/05/2016" />
<#assign data3 = "19/06/2016" />
<#assign events_list = [
  {"name":"Event Lorem", "date":data1?date},
  {"name":"Event Lipsum", "date":data2?date},
  {"name":"Event Free", "date":data2?date},
  {"name":"Event Dolor", "date":data3?date},
  {"name":"Event Sit", "date":data1?date}
] />




<h5>Order by date:</h5>
<#assign lastDate = dataNull?date>
<#list events_list?sort_by("date") as event>

    <#if lastDate != event.date >
      <p><b> ${event.date}</b></p>
    </#if>

    <#assign lastDate = event.date >
    <p>${event.name}: ${event.date}</p>

</#list>
```

Order by date:

**14/05/2016**

Event Lorem: 14/05/2016 14/05/2016

Event Sit: 14/05/2016 14/05/2016

**20/05/2016**

Event Lipsum: 20/05/2016 20/05/2016

Event Free: 20/05/2016 20/05/2016

**19/06/2016**

Event Dolor: 19/06/2016 19/06/2016

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to also group by month?

Comment: Thinking about it I think you could do just change the date format to include month and year and then compare if the month and year are the same, and if not then assume it's another group of data.

Answer (score 1):

See also this answer about how to implement grouped listing with a macro. I think this is more reusable then the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61588885/606679