# Netsted Grouping in Freemarker Netsuite Advance PDF

Tags: filtering, grouping

I have read this article

[How to properly group records when executing a <#list>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578682/how-to-properly-group-records-when-executing-a-list/61588885#61588885)

about Grouping. I do not understand the last word that we can use the grouping at 2 or 3 levels.
How can I achieve 2 or 3 level grouping in Advance PDF in netsuite using Freemarker?

Here is example

```
Project A
   Project Task 1   Total Qty Total Hrs
   Project Task 2 Total Qty Total Hrs
Project B
  Project Task 1
Project C
  Project Task 2
  Project Task 3
```

A project has task and same task can be part of the parent project. Can someone help me grouping and then printing respective details

Or how to filter by one group, print its detail then go to next group etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct approach to do this, you can first form your data in json format the result you want to show, save that json on a custom field and then you can read that json in adv pdf template.

Comment: Hi Sachin, can you give more detail how this can be achieved.