# How to properly group records when executing a <#list> for a Saved Search

Tags: freemarker

New to the forum but have been working with NetSuite for about 3 years and using this site as a resource. I was hoping someone could help me understand the answer to the following question, [How to properly group records when executing a <#list>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578682/how-to-properly-group-records-when-executing-a-list), so that I could adapt it to be used when pulling a saved search for items?

Thanks for the quick response! I've been trying to use the code you provided as a template and hoped you could take a quick look. For the macro, I modified as follows.

```
<#macro listGroups results groupField>
  <#if results?size == 0><#return></#if>
  <#local sortedResults = results?sort_by(groupField)>
  <#local groupStart = 0>
  <#list sortedResults as result>
    <#if !result?is_first && result[groupField] != lastResult[groupField]>
      <#local groupEnd = result?index>
      <#nested lastResult[groupField], sortedResults[groupStart ..< groupEnd]>
      <#local groupStart = groupEnd>
    </#if>
    <#local lastResult = result>
  </#list>
  <#local groupEnd = sortedResults?size>
  <#nested lastResult[groupField], sortedResults[groupStart ..< groupEnd]>
</#macro>
```

When I used the macro later, I modified as follows.

```
<@listGroups record.result "result.class"; groupName, groupResults>
  <p>${groupName}</p>
  <table>
    <#list groupResults as groupResult>
       <tr>
          <td>${groupResult.itemid}</td>
          <td>${groupResult.salesdescription}</td>
          <td>${groupResult.othervendor}</td>
          <td>${groupResult.vendorcost}</td>
      </tr>
    </#list>
  </table>
</@listGroups>
```

This is the error I'm getting, but I feel like I'm very close to what I'd like to accomplish.

### *The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> record [in template "template" at line 58, column 14]

### Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??

---

FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):

- Failed at: #macro listGroups results groupField [in template "template" in macro "listGroups" at line 3, column 1]
- Reached through: @listGroups record.result, "result.cl... [in template "template" at line 58, column 1]
  ----*

Comment: As of 2.3.31, the answer is still the same as for the question you have linked. Although there's a chance that grouping will be supported in the future, as this comes up way too often.

Comment: ddekany, thanks for the quick response, was hoping you could take a look at what I tried to do and offer any advice.