# How to check next value on List loop Freemark

Tags: xml, freemarker

Hello guys i wanna ask suggestions regarding my testing of Freemark,

Lets say i have data source in DB like this

[image]

Then i would like to have output XML such a

```
    <user>Raven</user>
<Purchasing>
    <ID>V003</ID>
    <PurchasingLine>
        <Line>1</Line>
        <Item>Turnip</Item>
        <Qty>11</Qty>
    </PurchasingLine>
    <PurchasingLine>
        <Line>2</Line>
        <Item>Carrot</Item>
        <Qty>23</Qty>
    </PurchasingLine>
</Purchasing>
<Purchasing>
    <ID>VV1X</ID>
    <PurchasingLine>
         <Line>1</Line>
         <Item>Pen</Item>
         <Qty>Pencil</Qty>
    </PurchasingLine>
</Purchasing>
```

So using Freemark, i create this template

```
<#list Purchasing as po>
<#if po.line == 1>
<Test List>
    <user>Raven</user>
<Purchasing>
    <ID>po.id</ID>
</#if>
    <PurchasingLine>
        <Line>po.line</Line>
        <Item>po.item</Item>
        <Qty>po.qty</Qty>
    </PurchasingLine>
<--Condition to detect last>
</Purchasing>
</--Condition to detect last>
</#list>
```

that im stuck on condition to detect last part.
It would be better if freemark could check next ID value (if not same then do close) or
check next line value (if next ID is 1 then close)

Or maybe there are any alternative suggestion template sample for that ?

Thank You

**UPDATE**

Thank You @ddekany for the sample code.
the current data i have is
[image]

and desired output is :

```
<Test List>
    <user>Raven</user>
<Purchasing>
    <ID>V003</ID>
    <Client>Cliphort Inc.</Client>
    <Address>St.Green Rd</Address>
    <PurchasingLine>
        <Line>1</Line>
        <Item>Turnip</Item>
        <Qty>11</Qty>
    </PurchasingLine>
    <PurchasingLine>
        <Line>2</Line>
        <Item>Carrot</Item>
        <Qty>23</Qty>
    </PurchasingLine>
</Purchasing>
<Purchasing>
    <ID>VV1X</ID>
    <Client>Light Inc.</Client>
    <Address>707 Tower</Address>
    <PurchasingLine>
         <Line>1</Line>
         <Item>Pen</Item>
         <Qty>Pencil</Qty>
         .
         .
         .
         .
    </PurchasingLine>
    .
    .
    .

</Purchasing>
```

ive tried to modified @ddekany sample code like this

```
<#macro listGroups items groupField>
  <#if items?size == 0><#return></#if>
  <#local sortedItems = items?sort_by(groupField)>
  <#local groupStart = 0>
  <#list sortedItems as item>
    <#if !item?is_first && item[groupField] != lastItem[groupField]>
      <#local groupEnd = item?index>
      <#nested lastItem[groupField], sortedItems[groupStart ..< groupEnd]>
      <#local groupStart = groupEnd>
    </#if>
    <#local lastItem = item>
  </#list>
  <#local groupEnd = sortedItems?size>
  <#nested lastItem[groupField], sortedItems[groupStart ..< groupEnd]>
</#macro>


<Test List>
    <user>Raven</user>
<@listGroups Purchasing "ID"; ID, Line>
    <Purchasing>
        <ID>${ID}</ID>
        <Client>${Client}</Client>
        <Address><#if Address1??>${Address1}<#else>${Address2}</#if>
        <#list Line as pl>
            <PurchasingLine>
                <Line>${pl.Line}</Line>
                <Item>${pl.Item}</Item>
                <Qty>${pl.qty}</Qty>
            </PurchasingLine>
        </#list>
    </Purchasing>
</@listGroups>
```

but turns out error on my program "the following has evaluated to null or missing "Client" ..."

Then i add the macro call become like this

```
<@listGroups Purchasing "ID" "Client" "Address1" "Address2"; ID, Line>
```

it said "macro only accept 2 parameters, but got 4"

lastly ive tried to add after semicolon

```
<@listGroups Purchasing "ID"; ID, Client, Address1, Address2, Line>
```

but got error

```
Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a sequence (wrapper: f.tstem.freemarker.template.SimpleSequence):
==> supplier_code
```

Comment: What you need is splitting the list to a sub-lists (groups), where items in a sub-list have the same purchase ID. Then iterate over the list of sub-lists, and inside that the items of the sub-lists. There's nothing built into FreeMarker for this (as of 2.3.31), but it can be implemented with `#macro`, as in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578682/how-to-properly-group-records-when-executing-a-list

Comment: @ddekany i got it, but how if i want to add other field under purchasing beside ID, i try to add parameter without changing macro calling it said error null or missing on field. try to put field beside "", it said macro only support 2 values, add on after semicolon ... said error ... sorry i didnt get used to for the macro,

Comment: You mean, you have a composite group key. I have updated the linked question with examples of dealing with composite group keys.

Comment: @ddekany i think its to add similar parameter before listing item which different, i already update my questions.

Comment: Try following the logic of the example provided on the linked other question closer. If you are using `listGroups`, you need 3 `listGroups` calls nested into each other. The outermost groups by `ID`, the one inside groups by `Client`, and the one inside that groups by `Address`. If you are using `listGroupsOfSorted`, then you don't need such nesting, as that (and only that) supports specifying multiple columns to group by.