# How to group and sort items in netsuite advanced pdf template?

Tags: pdf, netsuite, freemarker, suitescript, suitescript2.0

In netsuite advanced pdf template to print sales order pdf,

I am getting output for club type and club sub type as:

| Club Type | Club Sub type |
| --- | --- |
| Iron | 5 Iron |
| Putter | 6 Putter |
| Wood | Wood 5 |
| Wedge | Wedge 2 |
| Iron | 9 Iron |
| Wood | Wood 1 |
| Wedge | Wedge 5 |

Now, I want to group club type and sort club sub type within each club type group in ascending order like,

```
Iron – 5 Iron, 9 Iron
Putter – 6 Putter
Wedge – Wedge 2, Wedge 5
Wood – Wood 1, Wood 5
```

Please help! Thanks in advance.

Below is advanced pdf template item table:

```
<table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 10px;">
<!-- start items -->
<#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Qty</th>
    <th>ITEM</th>
    <th>CLUB<br/>TYPE</th>
    <th>CLUB<br/>SUB<br/>TYPE</th>
    <th>HEAD</th>
    <th>SHAFT</th>
    <th>GRIP</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
    </#if><tr>
  <td>${record.item.quantity}</td>
  <td>${item.item}</td>
  <td>${item.custcol_cc_clubtype_so}</td>
  <td>${item.custcol_cc_club_subtype_so}</td>
  <td>${item.custcol_cc_head_description_so}</td>
  <td>${item.custcol_cc_shaft_description_so}</td>
  <td>${item.custcol_cc_grip_description_so}</td>
    </tr>
</#list><!-- end items --></table>
```

Comment: Can you, Please, try to format your question better ?  (using the [edit] option)   see, for more info: [How to make tables in good format in asking questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda) AND [New Feature: Table Support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)

Comment: Ideally, it's done before passing the data to FreeMarker. But I guess you have no control over that. So maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61578682/how-to-properly-group-records-when-executing-a-list

Comment: Please read: [Is Stack Overflow a code writing service?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have combined club type and club sub type and stored it in a custom line level field on sales order record. Fetched values from that field in a advanced pdf and sorted this field. and its giving expected output.